# window is undefined when use react server rendering

Tags: reactjs, server, rendering

I'm working on a react project using server rendering. I found that I can't use window(/location/localStorage...). It will crash in server render progress. Furthermore, if I use a library only available for browser, it also will crash even import/require the lib only. Testing is everything available and sometime I have to write more code deal with server rendering. It's dirty and make me tired. Any other way to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean server rendering? You render in the browser. Server side code is different than client side.

Comment: react-router server rendering.
https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/13-server-rendering

Comment: @SureshKoya react supports server side rendering. See "universal/isomorphic" react. Everything is done on the server side and passed to the client as a single HTML string to be rendered on screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue today about "Library only available for browser", namely the one using window (react-chartjs-2 in my case).

After digging a little bit you can use the following NPM package to fix it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/window-or-global

If you don't want to use external package, you can also check if windows is defined in your server.js and create a global window variable if not:

```
if (typeof(window) == 'undefined') global.window = new Object();
```